# How can I run bitcoin-cli with disabled syncing?

Tags: synchronization, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin.conf

I have synced about 200.000 blocks and that's enough for my purposes. So I want to use `bitcoincli`, but when it runs with enabled syncing (by default), my computer works to slow.

**How can I disable syncing for some time?** Probably I need to set up something in bitcoin.conf, but I don't know what.

Comment: What functionality do you need? If you don't need connectivity to the network at all, you could just use -connect=0 -nolisten.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `invalidateblock` RPC. Bitcoin will not bother checking validity of blocks past that an invalid block.